# using log scale in a bar chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following data:

```
   Week 1    Week 2
------------------
A  0.04      0.5
B  0.2       0.7
C  0.04      1
D  0.4       0.5
```

Everything looks fine when I tried to plot a grouped column chart:

[image]

But after changing to log scale on the y axis it became upside down:

[image]

Edit: I would like to show something like my original plot but with y axis ticking at 0.01, 0.1, and 1 (rather than 0.2, 0.4, ...). Is there a way I can do that w/o using logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As log 1 = 0, all numbers between 0 and 1 have negative logs, therefore your chart is shown "upside down". If you change one of the values to something greater than 1 you'll see that this value is charted upwards.

The function `log10()` shows you that the chart is correct (e.g. log10(0.04)=-1.39794).

In LibreOffice you can choose where the drawn columns should begin:
[image]

With value set to 1 I get the same as your chart, with value set to 0, I get columns beginning at the bottom of the chart.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I would like to show something like my original plot but with y axis ticking at 0.01, 0.1, and 1 (rather than 0.2, 0.4, ...). Is there a way I can do that w/o using logs?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your chart with LibreOffice. With the default settings I get a logarithmic scale where the columns start at the bottom (at y=0.01). I can vary that by formatting the x-axis, setting the parameter "cross other axis at" in the positioning tab. With the value 0 I get what you want, with the value 1 I get what you have shown in your question. With the value 0.1 the colums start at 0.1 and go upwards or downwards according to the y-values to be represented. In Excel the wording is perhaps different, but you should have a similar formatting possibility.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you the effect of the axis positioning.